# Why does Mongoose want to cast my string to ObjectId?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this shema:

```
S_logs =  new mongoose.Schema({
    user_ip : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId},
    user_id : String,
    user_agent : String,
    canal_id :  String,
    theme_id :  String,
    video_id :  String,
    osef : String,
    time : Number,
    action: String,
    is_newuser : String,
    operator : String,
    template : String,
    catalogue : String,
    referer : String,
    from : String,
    osef1 : String
});
```

That I fill like this:

```
while (i < logs.length) {
    DB_logs[i] = new Model({

        user_ip : logs[i].user_ip,
        user_id : logs[i].user_id,
        user_agent : logs[i].user_agent,
        canal_id :  logs[i].canal_id,
        theme_id :  logs[i].theme_id,
        video_id :  logs[i].video_id,
        osef : logs[i].osef,
        time : logs[i].time,
        action: logs[i].action,
        is_newuser : logs[i].is_newuser,
        operator : logs[i].operator,
        template : logs[i].template,
        catalogue : logs[i].catalogue,
        referer : logs[i].referer,
        from : logs[i].from,
        osef1 : logs[i].osef1
    });
    i = i + 1;
}
```

There is no _id field, and I don t understand what use it have, but mongoose seems to want user_ip to be casted to ObjectId, that I do not want, user_ip is a data field, not a index!

How can I either:

```
-Tell mongoose that I do not want a _id
-Auto generate a id for each object?
```

And what did I do wrong so that mongoose took a data field for a id?

```
{ message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "157.55.39.208" at path "user_ip"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'ObjectId',
  value: '157.55.39.208',
  path: 'user_ip' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a simple typo:

```
 user_ip : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId},
 user_id : String,
```

should be

```
user_id : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId},
user_ip : String,
```

Comment: Urg, I feel the urge to hang myself to have been pushed to ask SO for a dumb error like this...

Comment: Don't sweat it. It happens to all of us once in a while.

Comment: Upvoting this answer for acute observation of Peter Lyons.

Answer (score 1):

take `user_ip` as `String`

```
user_ip :String
```